# Reference request for the fact

Tags: reference-request, banach-spaces

Does anyone know a reference to the paper or a textbook where this fact is *proved*
$$
\mathcal{B}(\bigoplus_1 X_\alpha, Y)\cong_1 \bigoplus_\infty \mathcal{B}(X_\alpha, Y)
$$

Most author are bored to write a proof and say that everything goes mutatis mutandis with the usual  proof of isomorphism $\ell_1^*\cong\ell_\infty$.

Also I'm interested in the reference for this ismomorphism
$$
\left(\bigoplus_0 X_\alpha\right)^* \cong_1 \bigoplus_1 X_\alpha^*
$$

Comment: By $\bigoplus_p X_\alpha$ you mean $\{(x_\alpha) \in \prod_\alpha X_\alpha : \sum \lVert x_\alpha\rVert^p < \infty\}$ (for $p<\infty$; $\sup \lVert x_\alpha\rVert < \infty$ for $p = \infty$), it seems? I don't know a textbook reference, but the proof of $$\left(\bigoplus_p X_\alpha\right)^\ast \cong \bigoplus_q X_\alpha^\ast$$ for $1 \leqslant p < \infty,\, \frac1p + \frac1q = 1$ is really _very_ similar to the $(\ell^p)^\ast \cong \ell^q$ proof.

Comment: @DanielFischer I do know that this is similar, trivial, easy etc. But I need a reference.

Comment: Unfortunately, that I cannot offer. Including the proof would make the paper too long?

Comment: It is already too long, so I'm looking for references for everything :)

Comment: But you're not yet desperate enough that an MSE answer would qualify as a reference, or are you?

Comment: Unofrtunately not so desperate :)

Comment: @DanielFischer I've generalized my question, so may be search of a reference will become easier.

Comment: Norbert, have you found this reference? If so, would you please mail me?

Comment: @TomekKania, unfortunately no. I think I had to write mu own textbook to get that reference :)